# CentOS - Add additional hard drive raid arrays on Dell Perc 5/i card

Tags: centos, raid, sas, scsi

We have a Dell Poweredge 2900 system with Dell Perc 5/i card and 4 SAS hard drives attached, with NTFS partitions on them.  We installed CentOS on one raid array on this controller with a different controller and it is working fine.

We are now trying to access the drives shown above and they are not being shown in /dev as sdb, etc.

sda is the drive that we installed centos on and it has sda1, sda2, sda3, etc.  The CDROM has been picked up as well.

If I scan for scsi devices then the perc and adaptec controllers are both found.  sg0 is the CDROM and sg2 is the centos installed, however I think sg1 is the other drive but I cannot see anyway to mount the partitions, as only the drive is listed in /dev.

Thanks.

EXTRA INFO

fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 72.7 GB, 72746008576 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8844 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x11e3119f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        8845    70528000   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_root: 34.4 GB, 34431041536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4186 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_swap: 21.1 GB, 21139292160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2570 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_swap doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_home: 16.6 GB, 16647192576 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2023 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_home doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

These are all from the install hdd not the additional hard drives

```
modprobe a320raid
FATAL: Module a320raid not found.
```

lsscsi -v:

```
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDRWDVD TS-H492C DE02  /dev/sr0
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0]
[4:0:10:0]   enclosu DP       BACKPLANE        1.05  -
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:0:10:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:0e.0/host4/target4:0:10/4:0:10:0]
[4:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC 5/i         1.03  /dev/sda
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:2:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:0e.0/host4/target4:2:0/4:2:0:0]
```

.
lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   66285  0
des_generic            16604  0
ecb                     2209  0
md4                     3461  0
nls_utf8                1455  0
cifs                  278370  0
autofs4                26888  4
ipt_REJECT              2383  0
ip6t_REJECT             4628  2
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8748  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         12182  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
xt_state                1492  2
nf_conntrack           79453  2 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2889  1
ip6_tables             19458  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  322029  31 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
bnx2                   79618  0
ses                     6859  0
enclosure               8395  1 ses
dcdbas                  9219  0
serio_raw               4818  0
sg                     30124  0
iTCO_wdt               13662  0
iTCO_vendor_support     3088  1 iTCO_wdt
i5000_edac              8867  0
edac_core              46773  3 i5000_edac
i5k_amb                 5105  0
shpchp                 33482  0
ext4                  364410  3
mbcache                 8144  1 ext4
jbd2                   88738  1 ext4
sd_mod                 39488  3
crc_t10dif              1541  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 16228  0
cdrom                  39771  1 sr_mod
megaraid_sas           77090  2
aic79xx               129492  0
scsi_transport_spi     26151  1 aic79xx
pata_acpi               3701  0
ata_generic             3837  0
ata_piix               22846  0
radeon               1023359  1
ttm                    70328  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         33236  1 radeon
drm                   230675  3 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            5762  1 radeon
i2c_core               31276  4 radeon,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit
dm_mirror              14101  0
dm_region_hash         12170  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 10122  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 81500  11 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="bc4777d9-ae2c-4c58-96ea-cedb342b8338" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="j2wRZr-Mlko-QWBR-BndC-V2uN-vdhO-iKCuYu" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_root: UUID="9238208a-1daf-4c3c-aa9b-469f0387ebee" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_swap: UUID="dbefb39c-5871-4bc9-b767-1ef18f12bd3d" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg_lal2server-lv_home: UUID="ec698993-08b7-443e-84f0-9f9cb31c5da8" TYPE="ext4"
```

dmesg shows:

```
megaraid_sas: fw state:c0000000
megasas: fwstate:c0000000, dis_OCR=0
scsi2 : LSI SAS based MegaRAID driver
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST3146855SS      S527 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:1:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST3146855SS      S527 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:2:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST3146855SS      S527 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:3:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST3146855SS      S527 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:4:0: Direct-Access     HITACHI  HUS154545VLS300  D590 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:5:0: Direct-Access     HITACHI  HUS154545VLS300  D590 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:8:0: Direct-Access     FUJITSU  MBA3073RC        D305 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 2:0:9:0: Direct-Access     FUJITSU  MBA3073RC        D305 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

i.e. the 3 RAID Arrays Seagate Hitatchi and Fujitsu hard drives respectively.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I have installed the megaraid storage manager console and connected to the server.
It appears that the two CentOS installation hard drives are OK.  The other 6 drives, one raid array of 4 and one raid array of 2 disks.  The other drives are listed as (Foreign) Unconfigured Good.

Comment: Please post the output of sudo fdisk -l and try modprobe a320raid

Comment: I don't get it. the 39320 is a SCSI U320 card. How can it be connected to SAS drives? Please post the output from lspci, lsmod and lsscsi too.

Comment: I think I have got confused, and the 39320 must have been connected to the tape drive (no longer in use). It must be on the PERC controller from dell.

Comment: Post the output of `blkid`